# Ruby: Calling instance method from class method

Tags: ruby

I want to call `some_instance_method` from `some_class_method`. In the following code, the class method is being called from the instance method.

```
class Foo
  def self.some_class_method
     puts self
  end

  def some_instance_method
    self.class.some_class_method
  end
end
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? You could make your instance method a class method if it has no particular dependency on the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Does what you want to do really make sense? Which instance should the instance method be called on? If it doesn't matter, you can do this:

```
class Foo
  def self.some_class_method
    new.some_instance_method
    puts self
  end

  def some_instance_method
    self.class.some_class_method
  end
end
```

This will cause an infinite loop, of course.

Answer (score 0):

To call an instance method you need to have that object already instantiated somewhere, you can't call an instance method without an object.

```
def self.some_class_method
  puts self.first.some_instance_method
end
```

Something like this should work

Comment: The point here is instance methods don't make any sense unless you have an instance to call them on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance you want to be the recipient of the call to the class method. So the new code is:

```
class Foo
  def self.some_class_method(instance)
     instance.some_other_instance_method
     puts self
  end

  def some_instance_method
    self.class.some_class_method(self)
  end
end
```

Notice that the class method is calling 'some_other_instance_method'. If the class method were to call the same method that called it, it would enter an endless loop.